Implement IAP on an android app without merchant account
I don't have any verified merchant account but I have a google play developer console. Some company asked me to implement IAP to my app than upload the app on my own Google play developer account. After google play review is done and the app got live on the store they asked me to transfer the app to their account. But is it okay to upload my app with IAP without having verified merchant account?!
